# hibernate.cfg.xml not found on the JBoss server on OpenShift

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jboss, openshift

Friends'm trying to connect my application in openshift through hibernate orm.
But the deployment is failing. You can check the error message in the server log:

```
    2013/01/03 14:02:59,296 ERROR [com.wavetech_st.util.HibernateUtil] (MSC service thread 1-4) Falha na criação do objeto SessionFactory: org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    2013/01/03 14:02:59,298 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/testehome]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception starting filter conexaoFilter: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.wavetech_st.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:26) [classes:]
            at com.wavetech_st.util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:12) [classes:]
            at com.wavetech_st.web.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter.init(ConexaoHibernateFilter.java:31) [classes:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
            at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
            at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1943) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1924) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
            at com.wavetech_st.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19) [classes:]
            ... 11 more
```

I am creating this application in Eclipse. I have tested it on the local server JBoss 7.1 and it works. However when I try remote gives the error.  I set the file hibernate.cfg the datasource before you deploy to OpenShift:

```
<property name="connection.datasource">java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS</property>
```

This is my directory structure:

[image]

This is my WebFilter:

```
    package com.wavetech_st.web.filter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import com.wavetech_st.util.HibernateUtil;


    public class ConexaoHibernateFilter implements Filter {

        private SessionFactory sf;

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {// executado quando o aplicativo web e colocado no ar

            this.sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            try {

                this.sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
                chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
                this.sf.getCurrentSession().close();

            } catch (Throwable ex) {

                try {

                    if(this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive())
                        this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();

                } catch (Throwable t) {

                    t.printStackTrace();

                }

                throw new ServletException(ex);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {}
    }
```

```
This is my HibernateUtil:

<pre>

package com.wavetech_st.util;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory  = buildSessionFactory();
    private static ServiceRegistry      serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        try {

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

            return cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable e) {

            logger.error("Falha na criação do objeto SessionFactory: " + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);

        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Please, help :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by following the hint of these guys:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/4934330/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934330/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found)
[shaunabram.com/tag/hibernate/](http://www.shaunabram.com/tag/hibernate/)

My problem was to put the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the wrong location. How to use Maven I should not put in the root directory but in the src directory root resouces.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate, I had the same problem in jBoss-Openshift and Mybatis but with your answer you help me, I attached a picture where I put Mybatis config file who is similar file as hibernate

[image: Mybatis config file and Openshift]