# HHH000040: ...SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I have a small application hibernate application without web server or servlet container.

After each change of code or configuration I should make following steps:

1.mvn clean install (in eclipse)

After it I see following staktrace:

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
...
```

If I click `project->clean` - this problem is disappear.

It is very annoying to clean project and when my project will bigger it would be absolutely uncomfortable.

How to fix it in Eclipse ?

### UPDATE

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934330/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found

Comment: in my case it is Eclipse problem

Comment: I use maven layout project and hibernate.cfg.xml locates in resources folder

Comment: I see. How do you call the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the project? Can you edit to show it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly familiar with this topic but I'm trying to help. Why are you returning a new SessionFactory in your `buildSessionFactory()` method and using the one you initialized above in your `getSessionFactory()` method?

For example in this example: https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/DVDStoreEE6/src/java/dvdrental/HibernateUtil.java
sessionFactory is initialized like so: `sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

Comment: I think it doesn't matter

Comment: Since I don't exactly know about the topic I can not help any further.
Well I hope the topic update will help you get an answer quicker. :)